# Most efficient way to determine if HREF is file or redirect

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a smart script that reports all button/link clicks into GA.
I'd like to separate redirects from file downloads. The tag used is always `a` with the `href` attribute specified.

So let's say I have the following hrefs:

```
"/"
"aboutus/"
"//www.google.com"
"file1.txt"
"file2.PDF"
"file3.jpeg"
```

Would the most efficient approach be having an array with all the possible file extensions and then matching that with the `href` or should it be regEx or something else?

Comment: A file-downloads is related to the headers in the response that you get from the server. If you take this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/myfile.pdf you will get a page (404) and your browser will not try to download it.

Comment: As Dekel says, *any* URL can result in a file download. `aboutus/` could result in a file download. `/` could result in a file download.

Comment: With server-side scripting & the right headers, any of these could potentially be a file download -- only way to be sure is to check the headers -- check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript

Comment: You cannot know if a URL that look like "a.com/b.pdf" resolves to an actual PDF file. You need to open a connection to that URL (and follow redirections/login/take other actions based on the response) and then see what the content-type header look like. Then again, the server can lie in its headers and say that b.pdf is a PDF file but contain other data, so you would need to verify the contents to be sure.

Comment: okay, i understand, but this is on a site where I know for sure the file downloads will always have a file extension.. (I'm not trying to write some sort of security script that will verify the links for the users sake..)

Comment: Sorry for not reading the question properly. Does this link help? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012044?hl=en#Download

Comment: It would, but we're putting in custom data attributes for more clear tracking, so I can't just go with the simple tracking inside GTM. Instead I need some sort of legacy fallback for the links that have a file extension, but dont have a custom data attribute set..

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comment, it is impossible to know only from the URL what the browser will do with the link.

The browser reads the response that it gets from the server, and based on the headers in the response it decide what to do (view the page, redirect, download, etc).

I think it will be much better to check on your server-side the links that you create, and if the link is a downloadable-file - add some class to this link:

```
<a href="file.pdf" class="downloadable">Click to download</a>
```

And on your javascript code check for `<a>` tags that have this `downloadable` class:

```
$('a.downloadable').click(function() {
    // Do whatever you need once the link was clicked.
})
```

Another option (If you really want to) is to send a `HEAD` request, parse the response-headers, and based on the headers to decide what to do:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
        type: "HEAD",
        async: true,
        url: URL,
    }).done(function(message,text,jqXHR){
        // here you can use jqXHR.getResponseHeader('header-name);
    });
});
```

> I really advise you **against** this option, but if you really must do it it's here :)